# Using environment variables to find Excel directory and run script

Tags: java, excel, windows, type-conversion

In Java I need convert a .xlsb file to a .xlsx and I do it by run console command:

```
String command = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\excelcnv.exe -oice "+fileName+" "+convertedFileName;
Runtime commandPrompt = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {           
    Process powershell = commandPrompt.exec(command);
    powershell.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("Error converting file to XLSX");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I want to replace path to Excel file, because it can be different for each machine. I'm trying to use `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` instead of `C:\\Program Files (x86)` but it doesn't work, any ideas how to replace path to `excelcnv.exe` and make it more universal?

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.getenv("FOO") to get your environment variable

For program files directory use this:

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
```

or this for the 32-bit folder on 64-bit PC's

```
System.getenv("%programfiles% (x86)");
```

Answer (score 0):

String command = "excelcnv -oice "+fileName+" "+convertedFileName;
Should work if exel is in $Path

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass it as an argument to the program. Assume your class is in package *org.stack.com*, then you'll need to do the following :

Use the following line in your code (`args[0]` signifies the first parameter passed from the command line)

```
String command = args[0] + " -oice " + fileName + " " + convertedFileName;;
```

To compile :

```
javac Test.java
```

To execute :

```
java org.stack.com.Test my_dynamic_path_here
```